# Equivalent of awt Desktop in javafx?

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I want to check if system supports desktop ? In Swing i was doing it with `Desktop.isDesktopSupported()`, i found no counterpart of `Desktop` in javafx. I know i can use `Desktop` in a thread in javafx but is there any way to do it without awt.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

What functionality do you need? if you're looking for a way to open web pages like with `Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI("www.stackoverflow.com"));`, you can use this function:

```
this.getHostServices().showDocument("www.stackoverflow.com");
```

(`this` needs to be an instance of `Application`)

Comment: Why do you care about if the system supports `Desktop` if you don't want to use that class?

Comment: How do you provide an Application Menu in JavaFX?